# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE custom value

Tags: mysql

How to add a custom value using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE?
The column time_added is the 7th column and the file has only 2 values for the first and the second column. For the 7th column, time_added I want to use the unix timestamp when loading from file.

This code isn't working:

```
$result = mysql_query("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '{$myFile}' INTO TABLE {$table} FIELDS TERMINATED BY ':' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' SET `time_added`=unix_timestamp()");
```

Comment: I don't think LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE has a provision to support this.

Comment: Maybe you can do this with a trigger.

Comment: @Pekka You would be correct. If this is really important, you'd be better off writing a script to handle the import and adding the timestamp there.

Answer (score 2):

Why wouldn't this work?

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt'
  INTO TABLE t1
  (column1, column2)
  SET column7 = unix_timestamp();
```

Comment: Made few modifications to the text file,tried again and worked, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

The answer given by @iouri indicates the key element to address your question, namely the explicit listing of the columns populated by the `.csv` file, `(column1, column2)`. This line informs the `LOAD` function to only consider these columns when loading data from the `.csv` file and avoids an error similar to `Row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns`.

You will still need to list all columns, including custom columns, in the table definition. Also, the column names listed in the parentheses should match the names of the columns defined in the table definition. For example, if the table definition specifies two columns named `user` and `id` then you would need to have the line `(user, id)` above the `SET column7 = unix_timestamp()` line.

You may also want to double check that you want `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` instead of `LOAD DATA INFILE` (no `LOCAL`). As specified in the documentation for [load-data](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html), the `LOCAL` keyword affects the expected location of the file and both the server and client must be configured properly to allow for using the `LOCAL` option.